# Instance of Sql Server instead of full developer version on client machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Whenever I have to install software on client machine I install full developer version of SQL Server on client machine. Sometimes it's very painful if Client's machine has poor configuration. It takes so much time.

Is there any small size setup of SQL server which support all the basic features like Crystal Report Runtime ?

Comment: did you try 'Sql Server Express' ?

Comment: Crystal Report Runtime is not a part of SQL Server. It smth that has to do with SAP

Comment: Besides, SQL Server Developer Edition is not intended for production usage, so you violate the license if you use it in production

Comment: Crystal Reports was part of SQL Server at one time, but that hasn't been the case since SQL Server 2008 (which is no longer in active support). Microsoft's own solution is Reporting Services, while the standalone Crystal Reports can presumably use any edition of SQL Server, including Express.